# Provider org.apache.axis2.saaj.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl not found

Tags: apache-axis, saaj, soapexception, wso2-esb

i am tyring to convert my SOAPEnvelope from `org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPEnvelope` to `javax.xml.soap.SOAPEnvelop` using `org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.util.impl.SAAJConverterImpl` converter.
But while i try to convert i get the error like this :

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Provider org.apache.axis2.saaj.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl not found
        at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.createWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:175)
        at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:70)
        at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:128)
        at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.utility.SAAJFactory.createMessageFactory(SAAJFactory.java:133)
        at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.util.impl.SAAJConverterImpl.createMessageFactory(SAAJConverterImpl.java:720)
        at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.util.impl.SAAJConverterImpl.toSAAJ(SAAJConverterImpl.java:93)
        at com.mi.mts.dts.service.client.util.DTSServiceUtil.toSAAJ(DTSServiceUtil.java:18)
        at com.mi.mts.dts.service.client.mediator.DTSServiceMediator.mediate(DTSServiceMediator.java:52)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.ext.ClassMediator.mediate(ClassMediator.java:78)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:114)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:162)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:404)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:184)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Provider org.apache.axis2.saaj.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl not found
        at javax.xml.soap.SAAJMetaFactory.getInstance(SAAJMetaFactory.java:31)
        at javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory.newInstance(MessageFactory.java:130)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.utility.SAAJFactory.createMessageFactory(SAAJFactory.java:131)
        ... 15 more
```

i tried this [reference site](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SMX4-1089) to resolve for the same but cant get proper solution.
Any help or suggestion will greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi. did you find the solution for this problem?